# Javascript Regexp pattern matching

Tags: javascript, regex

`"CamelCase".replace(/[A-Z]/g, " $1")`

Produces

`>>" $1amel $1ase"`

How to replace all occurrence of camel cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need bracket ( ) for grouping

```
"CamelCase".replace(/([A-Z])/g, " $1")
```

produces

```
 Camel Case
```

Answer (score 2):

You don’t need to use a group. [Use `$&` to reference the whole match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter):

```
"CamelCase".replace(/[A-Z]/g, " $&")
```

And when using `/(?!^)[A-Z]/g` instead, you won’t get that leading space:

```
"CamelCase".replace(/(?!^)[A-Z]/g, " $&") === "Camel Case"
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something obvious but the previous answers do not act on CamelCased content but rather on *all* occurrences of uppercase letters.

This example preserves continuous blocks of capital letters and only separates a non-uppercase-letter followed by an uppercase letter (i.e. the CamelCase).

```
"CamelCaseTestHTML".replace(/([^A-Z])([A-Z])/g, "$1 $2")
// Camel Case Test HTML
```